# How I can make a new column with subtraction for two raws with +1 shift

Tags: mysql, sql, subtraction, shift

I have two columns

```
sum1   sum2
100    70
60     20
30     10
```

I need one more column `col3` which can be calculate by subtraction like this

```
sum1    sum2    col3
100     70      null
60      20      -80
30      10      -50
```

`-80` I can get by `20-100` and `-50` by `10-60`. I need to make subtraction of raws with shift on one

How can I get this new column by sql query?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Do `SELECT version();` and edit the question to add result of this query. Also, is there any `id` column in your table, from which we define the order. Note that data is in unordered fashion, and "previous"/"shift" terms are meaningless without defining the order by a specific column/expression.

Comment: this view is already the result of query with aggregations and grouped by quarters of year. The third column will be churn result of previos quarter (if you need this context)

Answer (score 0):

In relational databases, the records are by default unordered, so there is no inherent concept of *previsous* record. For what you request to be possible, you do need a column in the original table that can be used to *order* the records. I assume that such column exists in the table and is called `id`.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, this is straightforward using window function `LAG()`, which gives you access to the previous record:

```
SELECT sum1, sum2, sum2 - LAG(sum1) OVER(ORDER BY id) col3
FROM mytable
```

If you are running an older MySQL version, then it is a bit more complicated. A common solution is to self-join the table, and to use a `NOT EXISTS` condition to locate the previous record (this phrases as : recover the record has a smaller id than the current record, and for which no other record exists with an id smaller than the current record and greater than the joined record):

```
SELECT t.sum1, t.sum2, t.sum2 - t_last.sum1 col3
FROM mytable t
LEFT JOIN mytable t_last
    ON t_last.id < t.id
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM mytable t1
        WHERE t1.id < t.id AND t1.id > t_last.id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure that will accept 2 int parameters . Inside it write the substraction statement. Now since we cannot call this procedure in select statement we will make a wrapper class function that will call the procedure and then call this function by select statements and insert into 3rd column. We cannot directly call the function/procedure because we cannot perform DML operation in select statement while calling a function